# How to enable thumbnails preview on Files manager in Jolnir

Tags: pantheon-files, release-jolnir

Can't enable thumbnails preview on Files manager in Jolnir.
Already tried editing:

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/tumbler/tumbler.rc
```

any suggestion?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "thumbnail preview"?  There is no previewer built in to FIles but thumbnails should appear by default unless you are are viewing a remote folder.  Try looking at the folder context menu (secondary-click on the background).  There should be an option "Show thumbnails" or "Hide thumbnails" depending whether you are looking at a local or remote folder.

Comment: OHHHH! I haven't notice there's a hide preview option in the context menu, disabled it and preview is back. thank you!